# How to use cssSelector with targeting any number?

Tags: java, regex, selenium

I got this html code

```html
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 item " data-product-id="6718">
```

I use generally

```
item.findElements(By.cssSelector("li [data-product-id*=\"6718\"]"));
```

This will find the element.

But I need a way to find without knowing the number? Is there any wildcard which will support it?

---

Update:
In case of anything then `li[data-product-id]` would work. But if just numbers then it is unknown.

Comment: @Ivar are you sure? doesnt seem like it. This is targeting Java regex cssSelector

Comment: Yes accepted. you can write as answer

Comment: @Ivar But it doesnt answer if only numbers

Comment: That id is always going to be a number so `li[data-product-id]` is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will match number only with any length.

```
//li[not(translate(@data-product-id, '0123456789', ''))]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved with some restrictions, but only using `xpath` and if the number is of the same length every time (`4` for this example), try this:

```
item.findElements(By.xpath("//li[translate(@data-product-id, '0123456789', 'xxxxxxxxxx')='xxxx']"));
```

This will match what you are looking for.

Comment: It is unfortunately different lengths too.